# How to run efficient group_by statement using dplyr in R

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with multiple duplicate IDs which have different categorical values. Following is an example data set.

```
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
DUMMY_DATA <- data.frame(ID = c(11,22,22,33,33,33,44,44,55,55,55,55),
                     CATEGORY1 = c("E","B","C","C","C","D","A","A","B","C","E","B"),
                     CATEGORY2 = c ("AA","AA","BB","CC","DD","BB","AA","EE","AA","CC","BB","EE"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> DUMMY_DATA
   ID CATEGORY1 CATEGORY2
1  11         E        AA
2  22         B        AA
3  22         C        BB
4  33         C        CC
5  33         C        DD
6  33         D        BB
7  44         A        AA
8  44         A        EE
9  55         B        AA
10 55         C        CC
11 55         E        BB
12 55         B        EE
```

I want to aggregate values of ID from another dataset which gives the rank of categorical values. AS follows.

```
Category_Rank1 <- data.frame(VAR = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                        RANK = c(1,2,3,4,5),stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
> Category_Rank1
  VAR RANK
1   A    1
2   B    2
3   C    3
4   D    4
5   E    5

Category_Rank2 <- data.frame(VAR = c("AA","BB","CC","DD","EE"),
                            RANK = c(1,2,3,4,5),stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

> Category_Rank2
  VAR RANK
1  AA    1
2  BB    2
3  CC    3
4  DD    4
5  EE    5
```

For each group of IDs from DUMMY_DAT I want to look up the Category_Rank and then alot that category to the ID which has the best rank. Following is my solution.

```
hierarchyTransform <- function(x,dataset){
  x <- unique(x)
  dataset <- dataset%>%
    filter(dataset[,1] %in% x)
  dataset <- dataset%>%
    filter(dataset[,2] == min(dataset[,2]))
  return(dataset[1,1])
}


NEW_DATA <- DUMMY_DATA%>%
          group_by(ID)%>%
          summarise(CATEGORY1_CLEAN = hierarchyTransform(x=CATEGORY1,
                                                         dataset = Category_Rank1),
                    CATEGORY2_CLEAN = hierarchyTransform(x=CATEGORY2,
                                                         dataset = Category_Rank2))
```

I get the Following Result.

```
> NEW_DATA
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     ID CATEGORY1_CLEAN CATEGORY2_CLEAN
   <dbl>           <chr>           <chr>
1    11               E              AA
2    22               B              AA
3    33               C              BB
4    44               A              AA
5    55               B              AA
```

This is exactly what I want but the problem is time taken for this operation. My Original Data set has around 1 million rows and when I group it based on ID I get about 200,000 groups. So the hierarchyTransform function is applied for 200,000 groups which takes about 15 mins for a single variable and I have to perform this operation for 10 other variables which increases the time. Is there any solution to reduce the time taken for this operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the rank order of the levels of `CATEGORY` (which is alphabetic in your example) then you can turn `CATEGORY` into a factor with the levels ordered according to the desired ranking. Then sort by `CATEGORY`, group by `ID`, and take the first row for each `ID`.

```
DUMMY_DATA$CATEGORY = factor(DUMMY_DATA$CATEGORY, levels=LETTERS[1:5], ordered=TRUE)

DUMMY_DATA %>% 
  arrange(ID, CATEGORY) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1)
```

> ```
>      ID CATEGORY
> 1    11        E
> 2    22        B
> 3    33        C
> 4    44        A
> 5    55        B
> ```

**UPDATE:** To respond to your comment and updated question: The code below will, for each `ID`, select the value of highest rank from each category column.

```
DUMMY_DATA$CATEGORY1 = factor(DUMMY_DATA$CATEGORY1, levels=LETTERS[1:5], ordered=TRUE)
DUMMY_DATA$CATEGORY2 = factor(DUMMY_DATA$CATEGORY2, levels=c("AA","BB","CC","DD","EE"), ordered=TRUE)
```

Now you can do either of the following:

```
DUMMY_DATA %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(CATEGORY1 = min(CATEGORY1),
            CATEGORY2 = min(CATEGORY2))

DUMMY_DATA %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(min))
```

> ```
>      ID CATEGORY1 CATEGORY2
> 1    11         E        AA
> 2    22         B        AA
> 3    33         C        BB
> 4    44         A        AA
> 5    55         B        AA
> ```

Comment: If my categorical value is age groups as c("60-70","70-75","75-80","80-85", "85-90","90-95","95-120") . What can I do in this case ?

Comment: Yes, just set `factor(df$age.ranges, levels=c("60-70","70-75","75-80","80-85", "85-90","90-95","95-120"), ordered=TRUE)` when you turn that variable into a factor. Then you can sort by it and `slice` in the same way as in my answer.

Comment: I have changed the question slightly. I actually have multiple columns, the arrange function is not giving the desired result in current case

Comment: Thanks a lot @eipi10 this is exactly what I needed, its fast.